# How to avoid infinite loop with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

When I try to get useEffect to fetch updated data only when data is updated, I get infinite loop because after every fetch, data array in dependency array loses refence. Is there a way to make useEffect only invoke fetch method when data changes?

`useEffect(() => { fetchFunc(); }, [data]);`

Comment: When do `data` change? Or rather: do `fetchFunc()` set `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Change => fire useEffect -> fetchData() -> modifies Data -> Data Change -> fire useEffect -> fetchData() -> inifinite loop

not sure what you are trying to achieve, but im assuming you want to fetch data from the server to modify data. Data is not linked to your server in anyway, so when an update happens on the server, data will not change. you need to fetch from the server to update data.

you have two options

**Polling**

The easiest to implement. Create a function which will poll the server at a set interval for any changes which will then modify your client data with the results.

```
const fetchTimeoutRef = useRef(); //fetchTimeoutRef.current will hold a value you can use to cancel the polling if required.
const pollInterval = 5000; //5000ms poll interval, 5 seconds

useEffect() => {
 fetchTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
   fetchData(); //this will modify data with the results from the API
 },5000);
 return (() => {
     clearTimeout(fetchTimeoutRef.current); //ensure you clean up
 });
},[])
```

**Websockets**

[websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) can be used to update the client with data in "real time" or on an event basis. implementation will depend on your tech stack.